# Android/WebRTC (WebView) - candidates crash connection on android hotspot network

Tags: android, networking, webview, webrtc, tethering

I'm making an application which is sending and receiving video and audio through WebRTC using WebView (to kurento media server- but this is not important). When I'm using a home network with normal router, the connection and video is working without problems.
The problem is when I'm using a network from my phone (where I'm running an application). What I found there, what is probably some pointer, what can be wrong is:

For ipV4:

```
11-28 22:03:25.944 5931-5931/eu.kros.t_medapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(251)] "Remote ICE candidate received", source: https://192.168.43.213:8443/tmed-webserver/resources/webjars/kurento-utils/js/kurento-utils.js (251)
11-28 22:03:25.945 5931-7323/eu.kros.t_medapp W/chromium: [WARNING:webrtcsession.cc(1555)] Candidate has an unknown component: Cand[:3:2:tcp:1015021822:192.168.43.213:59866:local::0:::0:0:0] for content: audio
```

And for IP V6:

```
11-28 22:03:26.015 5931-5931/eu.kros.t_medapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(70)] "Received message: {"id":"iceCandidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:4 2 UDP 2013266430 fe80::c8d:a2fa:f0d6:8d2a 63831 typ host","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}}", source: https://192.168.43.213:8443/tmed-webserver/resources/webjars/demo-console/index.js (70)
11-28 22:03:26.016 5931-5931/eu.kros.t_medapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(251)] "Remote ICE candidate received", source: https://192.168.43.213:8443/tmed-webserver/resources/webjars/kurento-utils/js/kurento-utils.js (251)
11-28 22:03:26.018 5931-7323/eu.kros.t_medapp W/chromium: [WARNING:webrtcsession.cc(1555)] Candidate has an unknown component: Cand[:4:2:udp:2013266430:[fe80::c8d:a2fa:f0d6:8d2a]:63831:local::0:::0:0:0] for content: audio
11-28 22:03:26.299 5931-7324/eu.kros.t_medapp W/chromium: [WARNING:tcpport.cc(395)] Socket is bound to a different address:192.168.43.1, rather then the local port:0.0.0.0. Still allowing it since it's any address, possibly caused by multi-routes being disabled.
```

Have you any idea, what can be wrong, or where can I look for a problem?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `network from my phone` - is that the mobile carrier? If so who is your provider, device/os version.

Comment: I'm using wifi tethering option to connect pc (which is working as server and peer in communication) and phone application in one wifi network. I have Android 5.1.